# How can I specify the auto-increment value of a primay key column?

Tags: mysql

How can I specify the auto-increment value of a primay key column?  I would like to initialize it to 18.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the value of AUTO_INCREMENT:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 18;
```

It can also be set to an initial value in the table create statement.

```
CREATE TABLE test1
(
    x INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    y VARCHAR(100)
)
AUTO_INCREMENT = 18;
```

See the documentation for [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) and [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your PK is an auto-number...

```
ALTER TABLE tblSomething AUTO_INCREMENT=18;
```